# edit php page that contains arrays inside?

Tags: php, arrays, internationalization

I am trying to develop a web page with php. I keep some translations on my php file which has array ( keys and values in it). Is it possible to load arrays into a form and edit the values of keys on form submit?

Thank you.

Comment: Technically, yes. You could have PHP open its own file, overwrite its contents and then save it again, so the changes are loaded on the next page load. But that's a road you *really* shouldn't want to go down. If you need the data to be editable by a web form, you should store it somewhere else like a database or a separate file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simplified example of how it could be done ...

**translations.php**

```
<?php
$string["hello"] = "Hello";
$string["world"] = "World";
?>
```

**edit.php**

```
<?php
if ($_POST) {
    $translations = '<?php' . PHP_EOL;

    foreach ($_POST as $name => $value) {
        $translations .= '$string["' . $name . '"] = "' . htmlentities($value) . '";' . PHP_EOL;
    }

    $translations .= '?>' . PHP_EOL;

    file_put_contents('translations.php', $translations);
}

require_once('translations.php');
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>

<body>
    <form action="edit.php" method="post">

    <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
    <?php foreach ($string as $name => $value) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td align="right">
            <strong><?php echo $name; ?></strong>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="<?php echo $name; ?>" value="<?php echo $value; ?>" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="right">
            <input type="submit" value= "Save Changes" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>

    </form>
</body>

</html>
```